# How do i post an auto increment into another table?

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I have an form. When i post it will assign evenement.id as auto increment I would like to have the same id posted in evenementontvanger.idEvent.

Evenement table:

```
id
title
start
end
```

Evenementontvanger table:

```
id
idEvent
```

Comment: Is the database MySQL? What is the development language that you are using to insert? please add tags or you might get the perfect answer built in COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

Get the increment ID using [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
$query = mysql_query('ORIGINAL INSERT');

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$query = 'INSERT INTO Evenement("id") VALUES('.$id.')';
```

Run this right after first query.

Comment: Per the PHP manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), the mysql extension is deprecated and should be replaced with a more modern adapter, such as PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You could use MySQLi which is basically the same, except you would use `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_insert_id()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your application code as @Piero suggested. Alternatively, a MySQL trigger would do it on the database side:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_evenement_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON Evenement
FOR EACH ROW insert into Evenementontvanger(idEvent) values(new.id);
```

Comment: For TRIGGERs, to be able to set them up, you would need to have a super user access to the database, which would be impossible on a shared hosting. Additionally, older versions of MySQL, for example, don't support TRIGGERs.

Comment: @Piero While theoretically possible, neither should be the case. A developer should have super user access to a database he or she has developed and a fairly recent version of MySQL running. Otherwise it's time to switch hosts.